# How To Concat JSON objects In .net

Tags: json, object, serialization

i need help to concat two Json Objects in vb.net

```
Dim obj1 as object = New With {
                 Key .product= VarProduct,
                 Key .price = VarPrice
                            }


Dim obj2 As Object = New With {
                Key .photo= {
                            New With {
                            Key .source = img1},
                            New With {
                            Key .source = img2}
            }}
```

How can i Join Thats two Objects in one?
I Need a result like this:

```
                 Key .product= VarProduct,
                 Key .price = VarPrice,
                Key .photo= {
                            New With {
                            Key .source = img1},
                            New With {
                            Key .source = img2}
            }}
```

Any help would be appreciated.